# Degree or extent of something

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I'm confused about expressing the degree or extent of something in a sentence. For example, if I want to mock a friend for being single, how will the sentence be? This is what I want to say:

> You're ***so*** single that I think you'll reproduce via mitosis.

Is this sentence correct? Does the ***so*** in this sentence aptly express the degree of being single? And please share the alternative ways of saying this - the way a native speaker would say.

Comment: Generally speaking, making a joke poses difficulties. Jokes tend to depend on context and, often, regional idioms. In this case we have "reproduce via mitosis" which just does not fit this context. You are correctly using "so" to emphasize "single", but the meaning gets lost with the end of the sentence. What was intended as a joke becomes crass (offensive) with this phrase.

Comment: The use of 'so' is correct. I would probably say "You're so single you'll reproduce via mitosis." As a native speaker, and in the context of ribbing a friend, I'd drop the 'I think' for sure. It makes it a little too grammatically correct and takes the bite away from the one-liner.

Comment: I think that is the exact way a native speaker would have said it.